Normal transfer in Geometry Nodes issue: the normals rotate with the object's rotation
I was trying to achieve the same effect as the Data Transfer modifier.
The Geonode set up that I found in the internet is in the image below.
But the problem is when I rotate the object, in this case the scatter object, the normal will rotate too. Object normal preview in shader or the one use Data transfer seems not moving with object rotation.
Is there a way to fix this? I don't want the normal to rotate when the object rotates.



Which one is the desired result?

The one where the normals don't rotate.

I see two objects rotating

The objects are rotating, but in the one on the right, the normal preview doesn't rotate when the object rotates.

You can just rotate the normal vector by the inverse of the object's rotation.
That is, use an object info node and plug the rotation socket into a vector math node (set to scale and -1) and use a vector rotate node (set to euler) to rotate the normal vector with the inverted rotation vector.
Edit: Correction - use a "Rotate Vector" node, not a "Vector Rotate" node. And don't invert the rotation.


Thank you so much! This solves my problem.
